# OSGi and Hibernate - not suitable driver

Tags: mysql, hibernate, osgi, apache-felix, apache-karaf

I got the following situation.
I'm using `Apache Felix` as OSGi Service implementation and `Apache Karaf` as OSGi container.
There is a bundle in `karaf` which should save some data via hibernate into a database, but I always get a `SQLException: No Suitable Driver found.`
I deployed the `mysql-connector-bundle` to `karaf`.
The problem is, in my mind, that hibernate whether imports the `mysql-driver-packages` nor my classes which should be mapped.
But I don't know hot to fix this. I'm familar to eclipse rcp where the buddy-policy fixes such problems, is there any best practice for this problem for `felix` and `karaf`?

Comment: Are you sure that `mysql-connector-bundle` bundle proper installed into container?

Comment: Yes, i used mysql-connector-java and it's marked as active.

Comment: Do you seen those solutions http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5982675/sqlexception-no-suitable-driver-found?

Comment: Yes but they don't fit. Checked my hibernate-cfg twice, no mistakes in there.

Comment: Please attach manifest for `mysql-connector-bundle` and your bundle that communicate with DB.

Comment: i think it depends how the mysql-connector-bundle is loading the driver. is it using the classloader then the bundle could be active, but there is no driver loaded at all or the more OSGi way to have an DataSourceFactory service (specified in OSGi E Spec 4.3). Unfortunality I do not know much about the bundle u r using but i would definitely have a look how the driver will be loaded as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What version of hibernate do you use? Only since Hibernate 4, hibernate is aware of OSGi classloaders, and it still doesn't have complete OSGi support. See e.g. https://hibernate.onjira.com/browse/HHH-7527, which is planned for Hibernate 4.2.

We used Gemini JPA with eclipselink instead as JPA provider in OSGi.

In the karaf eco-system, there is Aries JPA, which is primarly used with OpenJPA. See [Which JPA providers are supported by Apache Aries Managed JPA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10157556/which-jpa-providers-are-supported-by-apache-aries-managed-jpa)

Answer (score 2):

Hibernate can't access do data and classes from other bundles (at least in version 3.x; I don't know about version 4). It only works easily if all (methods using hibernate, pojos, mapping files, all libraries) is in the same bundle. It can't access resources in other bundles.

Please also see [my answer in this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12471804/osgi-fragment-bundle-with-hibernate-having-runtime-pojos/12480876#12480876).